# How to normalize email addresses without regex

Tags: python, regex

The problem is that no matter what I do, I cannot seem to make a function that normalizes (not validates) without the help of regex. For example, instead of my code printing `invalid` or `valid` email address, I want it to:

1. filter out `+` signs, `.` signs, etc. that are **BEFORE** the `@gmail.com` part;
2. make it so that the program doesn't discriminate between capitalized and uncapitalized letters (return the same thing).

Here are the current email addresses I'm trying to filter:

```
johnsmith+panerabread@gmail.com
# should return johnsmith@gmail.com
jOhN.sMiTh@gmail.com
# should return johnsmith@gmail.com
```

Here's what I worked on so far:

```py
def normalizeEmail(emailIn):
    if emailIn != regex:
        ch_1 = '+'
        ch_2 = '.'
        new_emailIn = (emailIn.lower().split(ch_1, 1)[0]).replace() + '@gmail.com'
        if emailIn.endswith('@gmail.com'):
            return new_emailIn 
        if new_emailIn != new_emailIn.endswith('gmailcom'):
            return (new_emailIn.lower().split(ch_2, 1)[0]) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(normalizeEmail('johnsmith+panerabread@gmail.com'))
    print(normalizeEmail('jOhN.sMitH@gmail.com'))
```

The `.` needs to be replaced, and anything after the `+` should be removed.

Earlier, I tried it with regex, but it never seemed to properly normalize the emails and would return my customized exception error:

```
Invalid Email Address
```

With regex, I tried:

```py
import re
    def normalizeEmail(emailIn)
    regex  = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/'
    if emailIn == regex: 
      return 'emailIn'
    if emailIn != regex
      return 'Invalid Email Address'
```

Output:

```
Invalid Email Address
```

I've been cracking at this program for awhile, and it's really frustrating me that I cannot crack it.

Mind you, the function cannot be too specific because it needs to normalize a dictionary of 35 other email addresses. Then, I'll sum down the list to the normalized emails and create a list of them.

Please help. This is my first 3 months of programming and I'm already dying.

I tried regex and expected the expected email format to be returned, but it wasn't, so I am seeking a solution without regex.

Comment: Did you check the standard library [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) module?

Comment: No, I didn't as I wasn't aware that was a thing. What exactly would it do?

Comment: Never mind. It can be accomplished with standard `str`class methods. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a trivial task for the `str` class methods:

```py
addresses = [
    'johnsmith+panerabread@gmail.com',
    'jOhN.sMiTh@gmail.com'
]

for address in addresses:
    name, domain = map(str.lower, address.split('@'))
    if domain == 'gmail.com':
        name = name.replace('.', '')
        if '+' in name:
            name, tag = name.split('+', 1)
    print(f'{name}@{domain}')
```

The code above will result in the following output:

```
johnsmith@gmail.com
johnsmith@gmail.com
```

Or, if you want it as a function:

```py
def normalize_address(address):
    name, domain = map(str.lower, address.split('@'))
    if domain == 'gmail.com':
        name = name.replace('.', '')
        if '+' in name:
            name, tag = name.split('+', 1)
    return f'{name}@{domain}'


addresses = [
    'johnsmith+panerabread@gmail.com',
    'jOhN.sMiTh@gmail.com'
]

for address in addresses:
    print(normalize_address(address))
```

Comment: Thank you so much I cant tell you how much you've helped me